# How to wire switch to ceiling fan

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

[image]

The picture is how the wires are arranged in the ceiling and on the wall switch.
My ceiling fan currently works by pulling the chain on it directly, but the wall switch doesn't work under any circumstances. I've tested the wall switch wires with a multimeter and there is indeed 120 volts running through them. The ceiling fan itself is connected to the black wire, and the light is supposed to connect to the grey wire, but when I tried it the light doesn't work. When I connect the light to the black power wire as well from the ceiling, then both the fan and light works, and that is how its currently set up. I'm guessing the grey light wire protruding from the ceiling is the same as the single red wire in the wall switch box? Then how should the wall switch wires be arranged so that the grey ceiling wire works?

Originally the wall switch wires were connected to a 3-way switch. The top black and bottom white wires were screwed together in a wire nut; the bottom black, top white, and top red wires were connected to the 3 way switch as well as the ground brown. I turned the switch and nothing happens, but there is voltage running through the wires. No voltage through the red wires though.

If anyone can shed some light I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Your color coding makes me think you might be somewhere on this planet other than the US. Please post the country you are in.

Comment: i am in the US. the grey wire is actually a black wire with grey strips on it. Other wire colors are accurate.

Comment: Are the "brown wires" actually bare copper?

Comment: Can you find the box where the other switch is located?

Answer (score 1):

Alright so we know that whatever you have in place is not following a normal wiring pattern and right know it's a real mess (example brown is never the ground). But if you are able to identify the conductors at the switch box with the conductors at the fan box. Here is generic fan diagram that might help.
[image]

This should get you started in the right direction.

Good luck.

Comment: I think he means a bare wire when he says "brown wire"...